# C++ creating and printing an STL list (instead of a linked list)

Tags: c++, list, iterator

So right now I'm trying to implement a list using STL but I'm stuck at what to do for the print function. I've searched for solutions but I'm having a difficult time understanding. I'm having some trouble using iterators in this implementation as well.

Here's my code:

AnyList.h:

```
class AnyList
{
public:

    AnyList();

    int getNumOfElem() const;

    void insertFront(int data);
    void forwardPrint();

private:
    list<int> *ptr; 
};
```

AnyList.cpp:

```
AnyList::AnyList() 
{
    ptr->begin(); //added
}

int AnyList::getNumOfElem() const
{
    return static_cast<int>(ptr->size());
}

void AnyList::insertFront(int data)
{
    ptr->push_front(data);
}

void AnyList::forwardPrint()
{
    //const list<int> & iter; //removed
    list<int>::const_iterator i;
    for (i = ptr->begin(); i != ptr->end(); ++i) //changed
    {
        cout << *i << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    AnyList list1, list2;

    list1.insertFront(10);
    list1.insertFront(11);
    list1.insertFront(12);
    list1.insertFront(13);
    list1.insertFront(14);


    cout << "\nList 1: ";
    list1.forwardPrint();
}
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. As of now I don't even know how to test whether or not the insertFront function works without the print function.

Edit: made some changes to code and marked them.

Edit2: Just going to include the screenshot of the instructions so there'd be less confusion as to what I'm supposed to be accomplishing here.

[image]

Just to reiterate - The project file came with the AnyList class, which includes the private member variable list *ptr and the function getNumOfElements() as an example of a working function. There's a lot more to the main file but I just included the first part that should work if I implement the insertFront and forwardPrint functions correctly.

Edit 3: To further clarify what I believe I am confused about, the examples I see everywhere go something like this:

```
vector<string> SS;

   SS.push_back("The number is 10");
   SS.push_back("The number is 20");
   SS.push_back("The number is 30"); 

   cout << "Loop by index:" << endl;

   int ii;

   for(ii=0; ii < SS.size(); ii++)
   {
      cout << SS[ii] << endl;
   }

   cout << endl << "Constant Iterator:" << endl;
```

Which is nice but how do I implement something like this as what the instructions say that I should be doing? What I tried didn't work.

Comment: Why not just use `std::list<int>` instead of `AnyList`?

Comment: My insight: you don't need `AnyList` at all. All you need is a function to print the elements of an `std::list`. And you can generalize that into one that works with different types of container.

Comment: Well we're basically required to implement a linked list as an STL list and the AnyList class was already provided along with the getNumOfElem() function as an example. We're supposed to build on it afaik.

Comment: OK, but you're not doing that at all. You're hiding a linked list in some class that doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: STL is dead a long time ago. It's now part of the _C++ library_ if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I don't see where you initialize `ptr`. It seems to be a pointer to nothing in particular. How is that useful?

Comment: I edited it to initialize ptr (edited post as well to include changes). Right now I'm getting an access violation error.

Comment: I see no initialization of `ptr` anywhere, even with your edit. Your line with the `//added` comment *dereferences* `ptr`, which is only legal *after* you initialize it.

Comment: How do I implement something like this then? The examples I've seen with STL lists (or they're just called lists it seems) are not ones implemented in classes like this, but rather are just done in one main file. If anything, did I even implement insertFront correctly?

Comment: @BaloneyOs It would help if you explained why you did what you did so we could understand your thinking. For example, in `list<int> *ptr;` -- why did you want a pointer to a list? And in `const list<int> & iter;` -- why did you want a reference to an immutable list? It's hard to figure out what you don't understand.

Comment: Yeah I am quite lost on the syntax so I'll do my best to explain. Right now I believe what I am failing to understand is how I can implement a list based on a class rather than just in the main file (which is in all the examples I see). The const list<int> &iter was a syntax error on my part. The goal of the forwardPrint function is to traverse the list that was (hopefully) created by the insertFront function and print out the elements.

Comment: Edited OP to include assignment instructions.

Answer (score 1):

In the `forwardPrint` function you have this:

```
const list<int> & iter;
```

That defines a variable `iter` that is not an iterator (no matter the name) but a reference to a list. That is wrong in two ways: First you define a variable that has no connection to your actual list. Second you define the variable to be a *reference* to a list, but without making it actually reference anything.

You should use your member variable as the list instead. So something like

```
for (i = ptr->begin(); i != ptr->end(); ++i) { ... }
```

---

On a slightly related note, why do you have a *pointer* to a list? A pointer which you don't even initialize? That means if and when you get the program to build you will have *undefined behavior* as you dereference the uninitialized pointer, which doesn't point anywhere valid.

**Don't** use a pointer. Use an actual instance instead.

Or, as a couple of comments noted, why wrap the `std::list` class at all?

Comment: If you're referring to the AnyList private member variable "list<int> *ptr", that was already there in the file and is used for the getNumOfElem() example function which also came with the file.

Comment: Also I made the changes you suggested but now I'm getting an access violation from reading a location.

Comment: @BaloneyOs The crash is probably because you don't *initialize* the pointer, you don't make it point to a valid list. Do your assignment instructions include to not change the member variable? Because it's stupid.

Comment: It doesn't specifically say not to change the member variable but the variable is used in the example function getNumOfElem() which was also provided. It seems like it would be strange to provide a working example and then expecting parts of it to be changed from the ground up. How do I properly initialize the pointer here? Someone above already mentioned that I accidentally dereferenced the pointer instead of initialized it.